# Magento search box in attribute list

Tags: attributes, search

How can implement search box in attribute list on my Magento template?

[image: Search based on category]

Another example is on yoox.com.

Comment: This is too broad a request; you'll need to being the programmatic part of the implementation and ask more focused questions. Alternately, have you tried looking at third party modules which provide this?